# Can I have null values in a junction table with more than two foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, data-modeling

My data model has 4 tables `Storage, Emissions, Infrastructure,` and `Projects`.

The `Projects` table references the other three tables with many-to-many relationships, and hence I assumed using a Junction table is the logical way forward.

The planned Junction table has the following structure:

[image]

My issue is that there are cases where a Project can have no values for Emission, Infrastructure, **or** Storage. It will always have a value for at least one of these columns, but not always all of them.

I know that junction tables use composite primary keys and hence cannot have null values for its columns. Is there an alternative to this?

P.S. The suggested solution for [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database) cannot be used in my case, as each of these four tables have standalone data and relationships to other tables not mentioned. The question here is solely about representing many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate junction table for each many to many relationship.

Comment: I know this will work, but it's not an elegant solution and complicates the schema.

Comment: anything else will cause you nightmares later.  It is the elegant solution; what you propose is much more of a hack.

Comment: just a few examples of the complexity of your proposed table: if a project has multiple storage and emissions, which pairings of those two go in which junction rows?  presumably you don't have separate rows for all possible pairings?  if a relationship is removed, you can't just null out a field, then you end up with multiple rows with all nulls for the relationships and joined selects produce extra rows.  so you need logic to tell whether to update or delete a junction row.  and your junction table would need indexes for all the different relationships.  separate junctions is so much cleaner.